# Windows 8.1 Store App: Lifecycle Foreground vs Background

Tags: windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, toast

I'm a bit confused about how to determine the state of a Windows 8.1 Store app. The goal I'm attempting to accomplish is to only show Toast notifications if a particular view of the app is not in focus.

I have a background audio playing app, and want to show a toast notification when the track changes, but only if they don't have the tracklist view on screen. if they navigate to another view or if they put the app in the background, I want the toasts to show.

If they are on the tracklist screen, and change a track, no toast should show, because the track being played is clearly shown on the screen.

is this possible? what do I do to detect the state of the app?

many thanks!

Comment: Can you keep a static value for 'NotOnTracklistScreenOrInBackground' and have that value set on navigated to/from your tracklist screen?

Comment: thanks I did think of this, but was wondering if there was some built in way to do it. I'll try this and report back!

Comment: so it appears that the onnavigatedfrom event fires when I switch views, but it doesn't fire when I alt-tab to a different application, is there such an event that fires when I switch my app to the background?

Comment: OnSuspending does, but only after a little bit (not immediately I believe). The other option is something like [this](http://www.reflectionit.nl/Blog/2012/windows-8-xaml-tips-detect-app-deactivation). I haven't found any more straightforward ways, but I'll keep looking a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the self-descriptive visibility events:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.window.visibilitychanged.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.windowvisibilitychangedeventhandler.aspx